# for loop inclusive or exclusive in python

Tags: python

When I run the following code, it prints. However, I expected only one 1 rather than two.

```
for i in (1,1):
    print(i)
```

**Output**

```
1    
1
```

Comment: You're iterating over a tuple which is `(1,1)`, thus it prints all elements within the tuple.

Comment: `(1, 1)` is a tuple.  You can think of it like an immutable list.  `range(1, 1)` is a `range` object.  It is inclusive of the beginning integer, but not the ending integer.  In math syntax `range(n, m)` is `[n, m)`

Comment: @hotspring if none of the answers answered your question, could you indicate what it is that you are still wondering?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are iterating over a tuple which contains two elements with value 1 so it prints `1` twice. Your code is equivalent to:

```
list = [1, 1]
for item in list:
    print(item)
```

If you want to loop over a [range of numbers](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/):

```
for i in range(1, 2):
    print(i)
```

Or if you want to print unique numbers or values in list or tuple convert it into the set it will automatically remove the duplicates

```
newList = set(list)
for value in newList:
    print(value)
```

Comment: Good point about `range`, it didn't occur to me that OP might have been thinking of it that way.  But that makes sense implicitly given the "inclusive" wording.

Answer (score 3):

Sets and tuples are different.  I suspect you are confusing them.  On a set:

```
for i in {1, 1}:
    print(i)
```

> 1

On a tuple:

```
for i in (1, 1):
    print(i)
```

> 1
>   1

Think of sets as being like sets in math, and tuples as being more like sequences - you can have redundancies in a sequence, but not in a set.

After reading @KeshavGarg's answer, I suspect you thought that `(a,b)` in Python would mean `stuff in a through b`.  As you're probably aware by now, this is not the case - you need `range` to get that.  Interestingly (and I admit tangentially), the syntax we're discussing here varies by language.  In MATLAB, the range syntax looks a lot more like what I assume you thought the Python range syntax was:

```
>> for i=1:4
disp(i)
end
```

[There has been some discussion](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0204/) of implementing range literals (a la Matlab) in Python.  This introduces a variety of interesting new problems, which you can read about in the documentation linked in the previous sentence.

Answer (score 0):

For loops are always inclusive in Python: they always run over all elements of the iterator (other than exceptions such as `break`, etc.). What probably has you confused is the `range` syntax. `range(1,1)` will create a `range` object with one element. It is the `range` function, not the for-loop, that is exclusive, in the sense of not including the `stop` argument in the `range` object.